# 16.04 freezes randomly, mostly while using firefox

Tags: 16.04, freeze, amd-graphics

I have tried installing Ubuntu on my new notebook.

Specs:https://www.amazon.de/HP-17-y067ng-1HF29EA-Dual-Core-R3-Grafikkarte/dp/B01MTEWYJH/ref=sr_1_6?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1504678737&sr=1-6&keywords=laptop&th=1

The system keeps completely freezing after some time, mostly while using firefox, but also outside of it. I think it is related to the graphicscard or drivers, because when booting "failed to load gpu irq pops up".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have "swap" defined? If not, when your system exhausts memory, it fails. In a terminal window, type `free`. Still in the terminal window, read `man mkswap` and `man swapon`.

Comment: Yes, i have a swap partition of 7,5 GB defined.